# Is there a way to grab the name of a casted column in SAP Hana jdbc driver?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, hana

Given the following query: `SELECT fc as A, sc as B, TO_BIGINT(tc) as C from....`

I want to grab the column names `fc`, `sc`, `tc` from the result set.
I do the following:

```
ResultSet rs = statment.executeQuery(query);
ResultSetMetData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
for(int i = 1; i <= rsmd.getColumnCount(); i++){
  System.out.println(rsmd.getColumnName(i) + " " + rsmd.getColumnLabel(i);
}
```

However, when I print out the values I get the following:

fc a

sc B

TO_BIGINT(tc) c

Is there no way to ignore the cast using jdbc and grab the actual name from the query?

Comment: You can place any valid expression in SQL select list, and generic expression allows you to calculate result from multiple input parameters, including subquery in select list (where you will use some column from tables not in `from` or `join` clause of the main query). So theres no practical reason to have such ability. Please, describe, what the task you need to accomplish in the end? Just knowing the column you will not have the ability to identify it's source. Maybe there's another way.

Comment: _"Is there no way to ignore the cast using jdbc and grab the actual name from the query?"_ What do you consider the "actual name"? `getColumnName()` returns the original column name (or, for this database, the expression), while `getColumnLabel` returns the 'label' (the alias or original column name if no alias is used). In JDBC, in almost all cases, you should use `getColumnLabel`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For expressions, the default column label is the full expression.

The example shows an expression (aka *derived column**)  with a custom label (`as C`) and that is what is returned to the client. That's SQL standard behaviour.

In this regard, all expressions are handled the same, and type casts have no special handling that would allow to "peak the original column".

Long story short: you should consider the **ColumnLabel** as the intended column name.

If you absolutely want/need to get the base column from the result set and you are fine with all the limitations, then you can manually parse the result from `getColumnName` and pick out whatever is within the brackets of any casting function.

E.g. if you get `TO_BIGINT( abc )` you look for whatever is between `(` and `)`.
That is the amount of detail you can derive from the result set.